# HttpErrors custom error page not showing up

Tags: c#, exception

I have to following httpErrors section in my web.config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultPath="/ErrorPages/500.html" defaultResponseMode="File">
      <clear/>
      <error statusCode="400" path="/ErrorPages/400.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      <error statusCode="401" path="/ErrorPages/401.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      <error statusCode="403" path="/ErrorPages/403.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorPages/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" path="/ErrorPages/500.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

This works perfectly, except when the exception is thrown in a pre application start method or the application_start method, a the default iis error page is showing up.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

hello

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: hello

Source Error: 


Line 67:         void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
Line 68:         {
Line 69:             throw new InvalidOperationException("hello");
Line 70:             context.BeginRequest += (sender, _) =>
Line 71:             {

Source File:    Line: 69 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: hello]
   DryIoc.Web.DryIocHttpModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) in \DryIoc\Web\DryIocWeb.cs:69
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +536
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): hello]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9963856
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1637.0
```

How can I get the custom error page, even when an exception is thrown at start up?

Comment: are they displayed when you build for release?

Comment: yes they are also displayed in release mode

Comment: are you using an ISS version 7 or newer?

Comment: I am working locally with IIS express

Comment: and which version?